# R removes color and transparency when exporting the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor

I've created a script to predict fragment distribution of genomic DNA digested with a restriction enzyme. Anyways, I use ggplot2 to plot this fragment distribution in a form similar to an electrophoresis gel. When I run the script, the preview window shows the graph correctly. However, when I run the script to save the file - I lose the transparency and color changes from grey to black. Any idea how to make the exported file more consistent with the preview?

Code:

```r
F4 <- ggplot(GD, aes(x=GD$V1, y=GD$V2)) 
  + geom_jitter(width = 0.4, height = 0.01, shape = 15,  alpha=0.002, color="grey10")  
  + scale_y_continuous(breaks = GDYlab, label = GDYlabID, name=NULL, limits = c(4.5, 9.5)) 
  + scale_x_continuous(breaks = GDXlab, label = GDXlabID, name=NULL, position = "top") 
  + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())

 F4

ggsave(paste("/Users/franjo/Desktop/",format(Sys.Date(),"%Y.%m.%d.GelDigest"),format(Sys.time(),".at.%H.%M.%S"),".png",sep=""), device = "png", dpi = 320, units="in", width=5, height=5, limitsize = TRUE)
```

The first image shows the preview. Second shows the export.

Things I've tried to do:

1. Exporting directly with quartz.save
2. Using different types of color notations (hex, rgb, name)
3. Using geom_point with position="jitter" instead of geom_jitter
4. Saving as different file types

[image: What it's supposed to look like]

[image: What it looks like]

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/318) could be related. If the reason is the same I was facing, the solution is to make sure that the window with the graph is open before using `ggsave()`. Note that the issue on this link is for a different package, but the package used `ggsave()` code. So even if things do not seem related, it may be the same problem

Comment: I have the window with the graph open before and, I guess, during saving. Albeit I do see changes in font size, I'm mostly bothered by the change in color because it obscures the distribution of the fragments. Thanks though, I'll make sure to keep that thread in mind should I experience similar issues.

Comment: Right. My problem was with font size. I thought that the transparency might be the same, but apparently not. Maybe you should consider posting an issue on the ggplot package repository. This could be a bug

Comment: and now print it out and it will likely even be blacker! screens/ devices may always differ in how they show your graphs. print your graphs and see if they still show what you want to show, that way you can check if your visualisation is appropriate. One workaround for your problem could be to reduce the alpha even further, and / or to make the bars white and plot them in the foreground of your jitter. also, generally, remove `$` from your `aes` call